# Adding Encryption to a Specific Field in an Existing Product Form

Tags: emails

I'd like to add **encryption** to **one of the fields** in a **product form** on my site. I want to do this because my hosting provider **doesn't send outbound email using TLS** and users receive emails with this problem:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6330403?p=tls&hl=en&rd=1

Nothing sensitive contained in those emails, but I don't like it. [See here for more information about what I've been working on](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190170/email-sent-to-customer-from-drupal-has-red-lock-icon-in-the-email?noredirect=1#comment230578_190170). I took the second comment from that DA thread and **tried implementing encryption**.

**My So-Far Unsuccessful attempt at Encryption:**

1. First, I installed [Encrypt](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt). Then I installed [Encrypt Form API](https://www.drupal.org/project/encryptfapi). I enabled both of course.
2. Next, I opened up my custom module that uses hook_form_alter on the specific form I need to change.

**I added the following lines:**

```
if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') { // this part was 
    already there of course
      $form['#encrypted_field'] = TRUE;
      $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_email_address']['und'][0]
    ['value']['#encrypt'] = TRUE;
```

**I also tried:**

```
  $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_email_address']['#encrypt'] = 
TRUE;
```

*But the first one is how the form is named according to the code inspector.*

**Unfortunately**, none of this helped me and I'm **still getting a red lock icon next to the recipients email address** in their inbox when they get the message. And **yes the site is SSL protected and its enforced**.

**Question:**
Is my code wrong and if so, can anyone provide guidance on how to improve it?

Comment: Please check my answer on your other question as its more related to your issue.

Comment: @Sage encrypting a form value isn't going to change the insecure transport method bluehost use to send emails, those two concepts aren't related at all. You either need to convince them to use TLS, or use an someone else, who _does_ support/use TLS, for delivering your emails

Comment: looks like it's time to ditch blue host.

Comment: Bluehost has been good to us so far, for cheap hosting of course. Do you have a suggestion for a decent alternative?

Comment: @sage I personally and many of the big boys use https://aws.amazon.com/  EC2 instances. [Introduction to Amazon EC2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsRBftzZsQo). Warning: Learning to use aws takes numerous hours of learning/watching tutorials. EC2 does not come with cpanel. So you have to do everything using a terminal. If you don't have the time to learn all of this, then it's better to use some other host. When I started I used HostGator and my drupal was so slow. Then I switch to http://www.interserver.net/ and it was alright. Although, I used the VPS cloud and not the $5 cheap plan.

Comment: AWS charges you per hour. The cheapest is a nano instance at $0.0065 per Hour which works out to $0.0065 X 24 x 30 = $4.68 per month, plus a few other charges such as data transfer, route53, should come around $5-6. Although, AWS does have a FREE 1 year Micro instance promo.

Comment: I see. Yes, thank you. I've actually set up multiple sites on AWS with the terminal. I'm studying Linux too so I can learn it all at once there. However, it scares me because if anything goes wrong on the server for my client and I have to learn it before I can fix it that's a stress nightmare. Do you have suggestions for ensuring a stable, backed-up, solid AWS instance for Drupal? Maybe that'd make me more comfortable using it for production sites.

Comment: Since I"m new to Linux I use Ubuntu desktop and likewise have stayed so far with Ubuntu AWS Server.